# Get source code from Click Once Application

Tags: c#, clickonce

Is it possible to de-compile the executable Click once application into the original source code i.e. the .cs file?
Using C#.NET Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't decompile it to the *original* .cs file, but you could use one of the many decompilers (such as [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/)) to decompile the executable into something similar to the original source, provided it wasn't obfuscated or otherwise protected in a means that prevents this.

This will require tools in addition to Visual Studio, however.  Visual Studio doesn't have a built-in decompiler (other than [Ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which is part of the framework).

Comment: @Devon: Use a tool like Dotfuscator, SmartAssembly, or one from Eziriz - see http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/  and  http://www.eziriz.com/

Comment: Reed :  I am unable to decompile a simple HelloWorld program using the Reflector decompiler. It says " @filename is not a .NET module"... Any idea?

Comment: @Devon: Nope - that typically works fine.  You could try Telerik's decompiler, or one of the other many free ones.  Reflector normally works great for that, though.